# Creating Class with Unknown Properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm looking to create a class that will have unknown properties. Basically, I pass an object to its constructor and it uses the properties of that object. This is easy in JavaScript but seemingly a pain in TypeScript.

I'm looking to add *several* methods to specific objects, not all - or shorthand something like the following (just an example):

```
function toString() {
  return JSON.stringify(this).replace(
    /[\u007f-\uffff]/g,
    (character) => `\\u${character.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, '0')}`,
  );
}

const obj = { pencil: '✎' };

Object.definePropery(
  obj,
  'toString',
  { value: toString.bind(obj) }
);

console.log(`${obj}`); // {"pencil":"\u270e"}
```

This is just an example, but how would I create a class that could simply (just an example):

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(/*...*/) {
    // ...
  }

  toString() {
    return JSON.stringify(this).replace(
      /[\u007f-\uffff]/g,
      (character) => `\\u${character.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, '0')}`,
    );
  }

  anotherMethod() {
    // ...
  }

  yetAnotherOne() {
    // ...
  }
}

const myClass1 = new MyClass({ hello: 'world' });
console.log(myClass1.hello); // world
console.log(`JSON: ${myClass1}`); // {"hello":"world"}
console.log(myClass1.anotherMethod());

const myClass2 = new MyClass({ foo: 'bar' });
console.log(myClass2.foo); // bar
console.log(myClass2.yetAnotherOne());
```

Maybe I'm overcomplicating things, but any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So your class mostly just copies anything passed into the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to minimize the amount of casting "as any" (by taking advantage of how you can narrow down the type of a class using an interface):

```
interface MyClass {
  [key: string]: any;
}

class MyClass {
  constructor(obj: any) {
    for (const prop in obj) {
      this[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }

  toString() {
    return JSON.stringify(this).replace(
      /[\u007f-\uffff]/g,
      (character) => `\\u${character.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, '0')}`,
    );
  }

  anotherMethod() {
    // ...
  }

  yetAnotherOne() {
    // ...
  }
}


const myClass1 = new MyClass({ hello: 'world' });
console.log(myClass1.hello); // world 
console.log(`JSON: ${myClass1}`); // {"hello":"world"}
console.log(myClass1.anotherMethod());

const myClass2 = new MyClass({ foo: 'bar' });
console.log(myClass2.foo); // bar
console.log(myClass2.yetAnotherOne());
```

It may be improved if you know exactly the type of the values, for example

```
interface MyClass {
  [key: string]: string | ((...args: any[]) => any); 
}
```

The `((...args: any[]) => any)` part is used to match the functions like `anotherMethod()`

---

**Edit:** 
Found a simpler way, you can add `[key: string]: any` directly within the class definition:

```
class MyClass {
  [key: string]: any;
  constructor(obj: any) {
    for (const prop in obj) {
      this[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }

  toString() {
    return JSON.stringify(this).replace(
      /[\u007f-\uffff]/g,
      (character) => `\\u${character.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, '0')}`,
    );
  }

  anotherMethod() {
    // ...
  }

  yetAnotherOne() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oG0DWApvAFzQQAuATgJYB2A5gLqli3wDcW0wA9rRZQCuwcj0oAKHgCMAVizYBKdF2wAzMdHG9%205aAAdKPPdDrRpMpZmzXo5ABbUIOA0cbQAvGdnPDexpxsAXy5grlEAZSo6enFLFWhKAnJBSlpoAClwgHkAOQA6AWjqVXhxe0cFPMS9cGACcXjsAHocAB1BAAYOgHZVAFp21SHVRib6ABpGzWA7MEowEQJKJXcAPmgAA1b2gBI0GbmF8iW8g8pEHgATAgBBcnEOyoiohnEARgA2Sr0wS8i5%204AFnG0AA5B1QQpAhtJjYFAFoKFsKwePYlrAknYrrFlDYmk1oHkiSEMFx4EkbrRUXYlllaPU4niCUS8iTQhhtBRoABbJAoCBvDzQekAdzgfMgEHEaGgNJAIB4pFBIrEIEuoMR8I5fAgPBABDyCpivOQkreeTlCvh0Hx0BVlDV0G1-D1BqN4g2mVypD2Jv5b2h1ttaAARJaeCHiCH7WqQ8FOa7DTxjRKoOaUWjKBj7NiFFrnVy-ZKAExC0Xi01QaXQdSKsFSOYawJahP6pMpysQYt5WtBgkNygFxPuotQbvk8iU6m0%20mxLVAA)

Comment: I had no idea you could type a class using an interface!

Comment: @Stev Strictly speaking, it applies to the instances (e.g. `this`), rather than the class object itself (i.e. the interface doesn't affect the "static part" like MyClass.someStaticFunction)

Answer (score 2):

Anything you can do in JS you can also do in TS, so this is possible. It does, however, go completely against everything TypeScript is meant to be good for, so it's a little annoying to write. You'll just have to cast any `MyClass` object to a type with the appropriate fields whenever you want to access them. Most conveniently, `any`. Otherwise, you'll have to go through `unknown` first:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(obj: any) {
    for (const prop in obj) {
      (this as any)[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }

  toString() {
    return JSON.stringify(this).replace(
      /[\u007f-\uffff]/g,
      (character) => `\\u${character.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, '0')}`,
    );
  }

  anotherMethod() {
    // ...
  }

  yetAnotherOne() {
    // ...
  }
}

const myClass1 = new MyClass({ hello: 'world' });
// casting to any:
console.log((myClass1 as any).hello); // world
console.log(`JSON: ${myClass1}`); // {"hello":"world"}
console.log(myClass1.anotherMethod());


const myClass2 = new MyClass({ foo: 'bar' });
// casting to { foo: string } via unknown:
console.log((myClass2 as unknown as { foo: string }).foo); // bar
console.log(myClass2.yetAnotherOne());
```

I fail to see why you'd want to do this, but there you go.

Comment: I’ve written a traffic interceptor (for a game). The interceptor logs all traffic, and manipulates some, to and from the game. While there’s a gazilion different types of messages, all JSON, the methods are all the same. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I wonder, why make copies of properties, instead of just using the original object? Why not add a property that holds the original object? If you design it to be used like `myClass1.originalData.hello`, it can be conveniently handled with generics.
And if the functions are identical for all them, do you have to design it to be called with an instance (`myClass1.anotherMethod()`) instead of, say, a static method (`MyClass.anotherMethod()`)?

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather you would be better just using objects and adding properties as you normally would:

```
const obj = {pencil: '✎'}
if(condition) obj['lock'] =
```

You could otherwise do what isaactfa says, but you would be definitively overcomplicating things